# travis deploy provider for draft releases

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to log the reports from the build and publish it through the github releases by setting it as a draft releases.

Tried publishing the reports using the travis provider releases. Followed travis doc https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/#draft-releases-with-draft-true

```
deploy:
  - provider: releases
    api_key: $GITHUB_TOKEM <I have set it as environment variable>
    file: build.doc
    skip_cleanup: true
    draft: true
```

Getting this messaged from the travis log
`Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because this branch is not permitted: suresh_branch`